# MongoDB aggregate count of other collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to join the number of comments of a user.

An exmaple of the user collection:

```
{ ... email: "example1@mail.com", name: "Joe" },
{ ... email: "example2@mail.com", name: "Peter" }
```

And these are a couple of examples from the comments collection (which stores more than 100k documents):

```
{ ... author: "example1@mail.com", comment: "xxx" },
{ ... author: "example2@mail.com", comment: "yyy" },
{ ... author: "example1@mail.com", comment: "xxx" },
{ ... author: "example1@mail.com", comment: "xxx" }
```

How can I achieve the following result:

```
{ ... email: "example1@mail.com", name: "Joe", comments: 3 }
{ ... email: "example2@mail.com", name: "Peter", comments: 1 }
```

Comment: Have you tried aggregate on the comments collection, and $group by author?

Comment: I need more details from the user collection. Actually, I want to give back the user details and add the number of comments to them

Comment: One option is to aggregate the comments first to get the count, and then lookup the user with the matching email address.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `$lookup` with data provided here. You only need `$group` and `$sum` into comments collection like this:

```
db.comment.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$author",
      "comments": { "$sum": 1 } }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7iE6Ei5SQDu)

**Edit to add $lookup**

To get data from the other collection you can use `$lookup` (which returns an array) and `$arrayElemAt` to get the object at first position.

With this query you have the other collection data into `user_data` field.

```
db.comment.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$author",
      "comments": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "email",
      "as": "user_data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "user_data": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$user_data",0]}
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EdGBAtoaUE0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I need more details from the user collection, that's why a lookup is necessary.

Comment: Updated answer with `$lookup`.